# Async await whilst waiting for events - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use async await within an event driven project and I am getting the following error:

```
tmpFile = await readFileAsync('tmp.png');
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

So far I have the following code (simplified):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dash_button = require('node-dash-button');
const dash = dash_button(process.env.DASH_MAC, null, 1000, 'all');

function readFileAsync (path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(path, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};

async function main() {
    dash.on("detected", function () {
        tmpFile = await readFileAsync('tmp.png');
        console.log(tmpFile);
    });
}

main();
```

My issue isn't really with the library below but rather understanding the fundamentals with async await and using it within an event driven script. I don't quite understand if this is a scoping issue or something else.

I am using the following event driven library for an amazon dash button:
https://github.com/hortinstein/node-dash-button

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have your async on the wrong function. It needs to be on the callback:

```
function main() {
    dash.on("detected", async function () {
        tmpFile = await readFileAsync('tmp.png');
        console.log(tmpFile);
    });
}
```

Comment: Christ on a bike - I'm being simple! Thanks for that Mark (p.s. I haven't downvoted, must be have been someone else. Upvoted to counteract)

Comment: I only had a quick answer because I did the exact same thing when I started using async/await.

Comment: I wish I just googled this without trying to figure it out for hours! Internet is the best gem to ever been invented. I bet you don't even remember you posted this! THANK you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `await` needs to be within an `async()` function.

```
async function main() {
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
                   dash.on("detected", async() => {
                     resolve(await readFileAsync('tmp.png'));
                   });
                 })
}

main().then(tmpFile => console.log(tmpFile));
```

Comment: If OP is expecting the `detected` event to fire multiple times, this would only correctly catch the first event.

Comment: @JLRishe Good point. Have little experience using node.js. Mark_M s approach should provide expected result for that case.

Comment: You don't need use `async/await` there, because you don't use the intermediate result inside the function. `return new Promise(....)` is enough.

Comment: @alexmac Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

> `await` only affects the innermost `async` function that surrounds it
>   and can only be used directly inside `async` functions

Your callback should be an `async` function as that is the function directly surrounding your `await` call.

Your `main` function need not be an `async` function unless it wraps an `await` call directly.